# Is there much difference between having a key (intA, intB), or having key (longAB) where longAB is the concatenation of bytes of intA and intB?

Tags: performance, index

This is a bit of an odd question.  Let's go with MySQL for example.  I don't know a ton about db internals.

Compare two scenarios, in one, we have a table with a composite key of the from (intA, intB).  Queries filter by range intA, and the intB portion of the key is to enforce uniqueness.  So we might do `WHERE intA > 0x123 AND intA < 0xabc`

The alternate scenario is where we have key (longAB), where longAB is the byte concatenation of intA and intB, in other words `intA << 32 | intB`.  Now our queries look like `WHERE longAB > 0x12300000000 AND longAB < 0xabc00000000`

So we'd get back the equivalent rows.

My question is, would these have substantially different impact on space usage, IO intensity, and why?

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server accomplishes this non-unique-key situation by adding a separate hidden integer column, referred to as the "uniquifier".

Comment: Re: "the intB portion of the key is to enforce uniqueness" If the only purpose of `intB` is for uniqueness, then either **a)** don't worry about uniqueness, or **b)** fix your data model so that the data is naturally unique.

Answer (score 4):

Worry about performance only after you've worried about the business.  If intA and intB are meaningful to the business, then NEVER EVER hide those attributes in columns that are "obfuscated" in the way you suggest.  Doing that WILL ALWAYS come back to haunt you.

You'll pay the price when someone wants to do a WHERE INTB = somevalue, and that moment WILL come.

With your design hack, the only way you could answer that question is by filtering the value out of your obfuscated column using some variant of MOD(yourcol,32BIT_MAX).  That means table scan by definition, unless you have been smart enough to also add an index on MOD(yourcol,32BIT_MAX).  But adding that index in addition to an index on yourcol is likely to make the overall solution ***SLOWER***, precisely the opposite of what you were hoping to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Minor issue with your queries: they are not equivalent. The equivalent of:

```
WHERE intA > 0x123 AND intA < 0xabc
```

is:

```
WHERE longAB > 0x123ffffffff AND longAB < 0xabc00000000
```

---

As for the main question, I don't think there will be any difference at all regarding space usage and efficiency of indexes (but you should test, don't just trust me).

The two designs will differ slightly if the columns are allowed to be `NULL` (so in first design you may have a row with `(123, null)` which has no equivalent in the second design). If the columns are `NOT NULL`, I can see no difference.

One thing that might be useful with the 1st design, is that you can easily define indexes that have the columns in reverse order or have only `intA` or only `intB` or combine one of them with other columns, etc:

```
INDEX i_BA   (intB, intA),
INDEX i_B    (inB),
INDEX i_AC   (intA, colC),
INDEX i_DBCA (colD, intB, colC, intA)
```

All of these would not be that easy with the 2nd design (you'd need to first define computed/generated columns and then index them).

---

For the rest, I agree 100% with @ErwinSmout's answer. If you need to use conditions that only have `colA` like the one you describe (`WHERE intA > 0x123 AND intA < 0xabc`) or `WHERE intB > 17 AND intB < 49`, then absolutely **do not** hide the columns inside another one. There is no reason for such complications, even if performance was to be slightly better (which will not).